# Использование callback

Tags: jquery

Добрый вечер, подскажите пожалуйста, имеется допустим три функции :
foo1()
foo2()
foo3() 
Необходимо запустить их линейно, друг за другом, пытался сделать так:

```html
var callbacks = $.Callbacks( "unique" );
 callbacks.add(foo1);
 callbacks.add(foo2);
 callbacks.add(foo3);
 callbacks.fire();
```

Но все ф-ии выполняются одновременно, подскажите как сделать последовательно, не используя settimeout

Стоит добавить: 
foo1(),foo3() - содержите animate
foo2()- асинхронный ajax запрос

Comment: таки надо add fire add fire add fire  писать )

Comment: @АлексейШиманский изменил, но по прежнему все также)

Comment: `Стоит добавить: foo1(),foo3() - содержите animate foo2()- асинхронный ajax запрос` - я так понимаю хочешь включить и выключить лоадер.... так у jquery ajax есть beforesend и aftersend. может их использовать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не совсем, объясню подробнее, 
foo1() плавно убирает прозрачность span, добавляя div .load с гифкой загрузки, вторым пунктом запускается foo2() с ajax запросом в зависимости от результата ответа сервера, добавляет  класс либо удачно, либо неудачно, foo3() - убирает класс .load возвращая прозрачность span 

Пишу кнопку для отправки формы обратной связи

Comment: ну смысл не изменился..... до отправки всё нужное делаешься в `beforesend`, после всех получений остальное (возвращение прозрачности и пр) в `complete`..... ну или даже `ajaxStart/ajaxStop`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо более ли менее настроил, беда в том, что в foo1() у меня есть delay и ajax запрос начинает выполняться раньше, чем проходит время delay, пришлось решить с помощью settimeout